# Удалить по пробелу из начала каждой строки текста, если он там есть(кнопка)

Tags: pascal, lazarus

Мне нужно реализовать кнопку, при нажатии на которую удалится один пробел в начале строки во всем тексте, если он там есть. 
Пишу на паскале в лазарусе.

*Как пример*: код кнопки, при нажатии на которую ДОБАВЛЯЕТСЯ по одному пробелу во всем тексте в каждой строке

```
    procedure TMainForm.btnIndentClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: integer;
  S: String;
begin
   memText.Lines.BeginUpdate;
   try
   for i:=0 to memText.Lines.Count-1 do begin
    S := memText.Lines[i];
    if S<>'' then
    memText.Lines[i] := ' '+S;
   end;
   finally
     memText.Lines.EndUpdate
   end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
procedure TMainForm.btnIndentClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: integer;
  S: String;
begin
   memText.Lines.BeginUpdate;
   try
   for i:=0 to memText.Lines.Count-1 do begin
    S := memText.Lines[i];
    if (S<>'') and (S[1] = ' ') then
       memText.Lines[i] := S.Substring(1);
   end;
   finally
     memText.Lines.EndUpdate
   end;
end;
```

Comment: Спасибо большое :)